# Automatically handle arrays and scalars for item assignment

Tags: python, numpy

I have a Python function that usually handles numpy arrays, and it does something like:

```py
result = a*x
result[a<=0] = float('NaN')
```

However, sometimes `x` and/or `a` are just float numbers and when this happens this code fails. To deal with this situation I am currently doing this:

```py
x = np.asarray(x).astype(float)
a = np.asarray(a).astype(float)
result = a*x
if a.shape == ():
    if a <= 0:
        result *= float('NaN')
else:
    result[a<=0] = float('NaN')
```

This does exactly what I want to do, but it requires code pseudo-replication and when we have many parameters `a`, `b`, `c`,... or more complicated conditions it is prone to errors.

I have tried

```py
x = np.asarray(x).astype(float)
a = np.asarray(a).astype(float)
result = a*x
result[a<=0] = float('NaN')
```

but it produces

```
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object does not support item assignment
```

Is there a better way of doing this? I would like to keep the notation `result[a<=0]=float('NaN')` and if `a` is a scalar apply it to all elements of `result` without having to manually check if it is dimension 0.

Comment: Having done the `asarray`, do you still need the `if`?  Does `result[a<=0] = np.nan` still work on a `()` shape `result`?

Comment: No, I have added to the question now.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want numpy scalars to behave like one-element 1d arrays, and everything else behave normally (the problem is that numpy arrays are mutable, but scalars are not). Semantically speaking the correct tool is [`np.atleast_1d()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.atleast_1d.html):

```py
# dummy input
a = np.array(1.0)
x = np.array(42.0)

result = np.atleast_1d(a*x)
result[a <= 0] = np.nan
```

This gives you

```py
>>> result
array([42.])
```

which sounds like something you want to end up with. If for some reason you want the result to be a scalar instead (which I do not recommend, as this would set you up for similar kind of loops to jump through downstream) you can convert the result with multiple approaches, but exactly how you do that would depend on the expected behaviour you want (considering edge cases such as 1d-vs-0d single-element cases).

Comment: I will have to test a little bit more, but I think that if you add `result = np.squeeze(result)` at the end, it is exactly what I want.

Comment: @user171780 for the record there will be no automatic way to distinguish single-element 1d arrays from scalars when you have `result`. But yeah, squeezing is one potential strategy (but that will also turn one-element 1d array inputs into a scalar result).

Comment: `result = np.asarray(a*x)` is enough.  `result[a<=]` is (0,) shape when `result` (and `a`) is (), so the assignment works.  We can assign to a 0d with `result[()]=np.nan` or `result[...]=np.nan`, but that isn't necessary here.  No need to squeeze the result

Comment: @hpaulj fair enough, one could use 0d arrays instead of scalars, because those are also mutable. I personally avoid both because the semantics can be surprising (perhaps just to me).